# ASP.NET Core resolving DbContext in Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have issue with resolving `DbContext` in my `UserManager` class.

Here is `UserManager` class:

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public UserManager(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 }
```

My `DbContext` class:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connectionString"]));
//....
services.AddScoped<IUserManager, UserManager>();
```

There is errror:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'MyContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'UserManager'.

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: You have a typo where your `MyContext_context` is togheter. Change it into `MyContext _context`

Comment: Its typo just here cuz of formatting but thanks edited :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DI *should* resolve `MyContext` with code you provided. Resolved instance will not work (see @Nikosi answer about [DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)), but it should be resolved/created.

Check your project for other/second `MyContext` class. I think you have two, possibly in different namespaces. "Go to declaration" (Ctrl+Click in VS) of `MyContext` from both `Startup` and `UserManager` files - are they referencing same class?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation: [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)

> EF supports using `DbContext` with a dependency injection container.
>   Your DbContext type can be added to the service container by using
>   `AddDbContext<TContext>`.
>
> `AddDbContext` will add make **both** your `DbContext` type,
>   `TContext`, and `DbContextOptions<TContext>` to the available for
>   injection from the service container.
>
> Adding dbcontext to dependency injection

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connectionString"]));
```

> requires adding a constructor
>   argument to your DbContext type that accepts `DbContextOptions`.

You were missing configuration options in your DbContext

```
public class MyContext: DbContext {

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is needed for proper initialization of DbContext, but not for resolving it.